# Unable to upload files using selenium webdriver sendkeys() method in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using below command to upload files using selenium webdriver,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("manageUploadAppViewID-AppIconUploaderId-fu")).sendKeys("C:\\UploadFiles\\images.png");
```

This code successfully loads the file in the path mentioned in firefox and google chrome. However it doesn't work in IE.

Can anyone please tell me why it is not working in IE. Do i have to use autoit or robot script to handle this IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an exception, if so which exception?

Comment: Yes. this is the exception i got.  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information). I put a wait time to load.. still getting this exception even though the element is completely visible